# Center Vertically not working in Android below 20

Tags: android

I created in my application list element with actions to swiping. The problem is that when one view is showing after swiping, the delete icon is not showing in vertical center. The interesting thing is that the problem is only in Android below 20 SDK.

ListElement.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listObjectRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/swipeBackground"
        android:tag="reveal-left">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/swipeBackground"
        android:tag="reveal-right">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contextRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:tag="front">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roundButton"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_0"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/contextRelativeLayout"
        android:background="@color/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to say that  android:layout_centerVertical="true" is not available in jellybean and below android version

Comment: yes, that's what I want to say

Comment: i didn't find any problem, because i use latest sdk and even it works fine in my jellybean and other devices. try to use it separately in a simple layout with textview